# Different IP addr. to all users [Windows Server 2008]

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, ip

I have Server 2008 Web Edition, one network card & 5 IPv4 addresses on it. I need to assign one different IP address to different user. How can I do it?
Thank you.

Comment: Hey user59178

Can you explain what you mean a bit more. When you say a different IP for a different user. Do you mean if you log on as user X you get IP P and if you log on as user Y you get IP Q. 

James

Comment: -1, You need to be **much** more specific as to what your situation is and what you hope to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, not seen one like this before.

Why do you think you need or want to do this, I genuinely can't think of a situation where this would make sense.

What's wrong with a single IP for your server?

Comment: Every user needs to have different external IP for specific software works properly.

Comment: Ok, but why have you put them on the server, it's just a routing issue.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand what I have to do

Comment: @user59178, are these users from your local network, or using your web site.  You really need to take some time and include more details in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Edited: You can setup a terminal server with IP Virtualization (IP per Session) using Server 2008 R2 Standard, Enterprise, or Datacenter only. Web edition can't, not any version. Server 2008 also can't, only R2.

Comment: Users connects to server via RDP - here they can use single IP for this connections. But for any network request they need to use personal IP address. I think, it can be realized as virtual network adapter which have, for example, IP address 192.168.1.2 for 1 user, 192.168.1.3 for 2nd user, etc. Sorry if my explanation isnt clear....

Comment: This makes no sense at all, please explain, in as much detail as possibe in your actual question above please.

Comment: OK, English is not my native language, so it'll be hard to explain, but I'll try =)

Comment: For example, we have user1 and user2. They're connecting to server via RDP. They need to have different IP addresses, for ex., if user1 opens 2ip.ru - he see 192.168.1.1, and user2 see 192.168.1.2 (just example, i know that that's local IPs). But this addresses must stays not only in browser, but for any network request.

Comment: I know about limitation in 2 connections, I bypassed it by patching termsvr ;)

Comment: Bypassing software like that is a violation of the EULA and illegal. Your not getting any additional help from me.